# How to hide trackbacks on wp-admin/edit-comments.php

Tags: comments

How to hide (or not to show, better said) trackbacks on wp-admin/edit-comments.php page?

I want to hide the comments with no email (also known as trackbacks) and comments with a specific email from the edit-comments.php page.

Comment: you do want them enabled on the frontend?

Comment: I want them to be shown on frontend, but not shown on the edit-comments.php and on the Dashboard widget named Recent Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not impossible, this is very likely to have ton of edge cases and backfire in some. In a nutshell comments are retrieved with comment query, which can be adjusted with something like this (if in admin and comment type not specified then only fetch normal comments):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'exclude_pings' );

function exclude_pings( $comment_query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( empty( $comment_query->query_vars['type'] ) )
        $comment_query->query_vars['type'] = 'comment';
}
```

However the problem is "any comment query in admin" is too broad and there isn't much it can be narrowed down by.

Overall I would not recommend to mess with this.

PS excluding by author is not supported by native arguments and would be even more tricky with need to filter SQL.

Comment: This helped me because I did not want to show trackbacks and a comment type named order_note (that has a specific repetitive email and author name). Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

To only show comments on the comments page.
Above the list there are 2 dropdowns one has the option to only show comments.

I checked the file which builds the data: `class-wp-comments-list-table.php` And the function `prepare_items`. It has no filters or actions to hook into.

As far as I can tell there is no way to disable trackbacks from showing.
Nor is excluding certain emails.

If you really want it you would have to copy the comment screen, and edit that.
I can help you get started with that if you want.

Comment: You should leave this as a comment rather than an answer to keep the discussion in the same context.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like hacking the core. Maybe a future version of WP will allow filters for this.